# sanity start command is running but showing following error

Tags: sanity

Getting error while doing sanity start: Module not found: Error: Part "sanity:css-custom-properties" not implemented by any plugins

what should I do to resolve this?

I tried installing sanity install @sanity/css-custom-properties
but still the error is showing